Registers Not Updating in 16-bit RISC Processor Verilog Implementation
I have attempted to implement a 16-bit RISC processor in Verilog, utilizing a two-dimensional register to implement a bank of 16 16-bit registers.
case(opcode)
    4'b0000: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] + registers[reg2];  // ADD
    4'b0001: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] - registers[reg2];  // SUB
    4'b0010: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] * registers[reg2];  // MUL
    4'b0011: begin
                if (registers[reg2] == 16'd0)
                    error <= 1;
                else
                    registers[res] <= registers[reg1] / registers[reg2];  // DIV
             end
    4'b0100: begin
                if (registers[reg2] == 16'd0)
                    error <= 1;
                else
                    registers[res] <= registers[reg1] % registers[reg2];  // MOD
             end
    4'b0101: begin  // COMPARISON
                if (registers[reg1] > registers[reg2])
                    GLE <= 3'b100;
                else if (registers[reg1] < registers[reg2])
                    GLE <= 3'b010;
                else
                    GLE <= 3'b001;
             end
    4'b0110: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] | registers[reg2];  // OR
    4'b0111: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] & registers[reg2];  // AND
    4'b1000: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] ^ registers[reg2];  // XOR
    4'b1001: registers[res] <= ~registers[reg1];  // NOT
    4'b1010: registers[res] <= registers[reg1];  // MOVE
    4'b1011: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] << registers[reg2];  // LEFT SHIFT
    4'b1100: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] >> registers[reg2];  // RIGHT SHIFT
    4'b1101: registers[res] <= memory[reg1];  // LOAD (register = memory)
    4'b1110: memory[res] <= registers[reg1];  // STORE (memory = register)
endcase

All operations are selected using the case structure as shown above. The registers are declared as shown below:
reg [15:0] registers[0:15];
reg [15:0] memory[0:15];
reg error = 0;

Here 'registers' is a bank of registers to perform operations with, 'memory' allows for memory storage and 'error' is an error flag.
The problem: none of the registers are updated when a valid opcode passed. For example, if opcode 0000 is passed, along with values for reg1, reg2 and res, nothing happens and 'registers' simply retains the values it was initialised with. Why is this happening?
The problem is specifically with the registers, i was able to confirm all opcodes and values for res, reg1 and reg2 are passed correctly by debugging with $display statements. The case structure lies inside an always block triggered by posedge clock.
Here is the full code for reference:
module RISC16(
    input clk,
    input [15:0] in,
    input [255:0] memin_flat,
    input [255:0] regin_flat,
    output reg [2:0] GLE,
    output reg [255:0] registers_flat,
    output reg [255:0] memory_flat,
    output reg error_flag
);
    reg [3:0] opcode = 4'b0;
    reg [3:0] reg1 = 4'b0;
    reg [3:0] reg2 = 4'b0;
    reg [3:0] res = 4'b0;
    reg [15:0] registers[0:15];
    reg [15:0] memory[0:15];
    reg error = 0;
    integer i;

    // Clocked process to update registers and memory
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        // Unflatten regin_flat into registers
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 1) begin
            registers[i] <= regin_flat[i*16 +: 16];  // Non-blocking assignment (<=)
        end

        // Unflatten memin_flat into memory
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 1) begin
            memory[i] <= memin_flat[i*16 +: 16];  // Non-blocking assignment (<=)
        end

        // Decode the input instruction
        opcode <= in[15:12];   // Non-blocking assignments
        reg1 <= in[11:8];
        reg2 <= in[7:4];
        res <= in[3:0];
        GLE <= 3'b000;
        error <= 0;  // Reset error signal


        // Perform the operation based on opcode
        case(opcode)
            4'b0000: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] + registers[reg2];  // ADD
            4'b0001: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] - registers[reg2];  // SUB
            4'b0010: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] * registers[reg2];  // MUL
            4'b0011: begin
                        if (registers[reg2] == 16'd0)
                            error <= 1;
                        else
                            registers[res] <= registers[reg1] / registers[reg2];  // DIV
                     end
            4'b0100: begin
                        if (registers[reg2] == 16'd0)
                            error <= 1; 
                        else
                            registers[res] <= registers[reg1] % registers[reg2];  // MOD
                     end
            4'b0101: begin  // COMPARISON
                        if (registers[reg1] > registers[reg2])
                            GLE <= 3'b100;
                        else if (registers[reg1] < registers[reg2])
                            GLE <= 3'b010;
                        else
                            GLE <= 3'b001;
                     end
            4'b0110: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] | registers[reg2];  // OR
            4'b0111: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] & registers[reg2];  // AND
            4'b1000: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] ^ registers[reg2];  // XOR
            4'b1001: registers[res] <= ~registers[reg1];  // NOT
            4'b1010: registers[res] <= registers[reg1];  // MOVE
            4'b1011: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] << registers[reg2];  // LEFT SHIFT
            4'b1100: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] >> registers[reg2];  // RIGHT SHIFT
            4'b1101: registers[res] <= memory[reg1];  // LOAD (register = memory)
            4'b1110: memory[res] <= registers[reg1];  // STORE (memory = register)
        endcase

        $display("Opcode: %b, reg1: %b, reg2: %b, res: %b", opcode, registers[reg1], registers[reg2], registers[res]);
        // Flatten registers array into registers_flat
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 1) begin
            registers_flat[i*16 +: 16] <= registers[i];  // Non-blocking assignment
        end

        // Flatten memory array into memory_flat
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 1) begin
            memory_flat[i*16 +: 16] <= memory[i];  // Non-blocking assignment
        end

        // Set error flag
        error_flag <= error;  
    end
endmodule


The Verilog simulation does not behave as you expect because you are not following good Verilog coding practices.  Specifically, you should not make multiple nonblocking assignments to the same signal.  While it is legal, it should be avoided because it can easily lead to unexpected results such as yours.
This line of code makes assignments to the 16 registers signals:
        registers[i] <= regin_flat[i*16 +: 16];  // Non-blocking assignment (<=)

The following line makes an assignment to one of the same 16 signals (assuming opcode=0 and depending on the value of res):
        4'b0000: registers[res] <= registers[reg1] + registers[reg2];  // ADD

The same is true for the other case items assignments to registers.
You should re-work the code to avoid these multiple assignments.  I recommend starting over, just trying to get one opcode to work with one 16-bit register (instead of a register file) for now.
Another general recommendation is to split the single always block into multiple always blocks.  This usually makes the code easier to understand and debug.
I also recommend that you debug your code by dumping simulation waveforms to get a more complete picture of why the code does not work.  It is usually insufficient to debug only by using $display.
